# Writing to file error

Tags: c, function, loops

In my code here I am reading a text file called `input-temps.txt` (this file I downloaded and it is placed in the folder of the project I am working on) that contains 25 temperature values to be read for each day. My program reads those values and saves them to an array. When finished calculating the max, min and avg, it writes those values, along with the hourly temperature table, to an output file that I will call `output-temps.txt`.

The problem with my code here is that when it runs the file cannot be found. I've experimented with other loops but had the same result. What am I going wrong?

Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//function prototype
void calc_results(int time[], int size);
void read_temps(int temp[]);

//set size of array as global value
#define SIZE 25

int main ()     {
    //Declare temperature array with size 25 since we are going from 0 to 24
    int i, temp[SIZE];

    read_temps(temp);
    //Temperature for the day of October 14, 2015
    printf("Temperature conditions on October 14, 2015:\n");
    printf("\nTime of day\tTemperature in degrees F\n\n");

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        printf( "%d \t\t%d\n",i,temp[i]);
    //call calc_results(temp, SIZE);
    calc_results(temp, SIZE);
    //pause the program output on console until user enters a key
    return 0;
}

/*The method read_temps that takes the input array temp
  and prompt user to enter the name of the input file
  "input.txt" and then reads the temperatures from the file
  for 24 hours of day */
void read_temps(int temp[])     {

    char fileName[50];
    int temperature;
    int counter=0;

    printf("Enter input file name : ");
    //prompt for file name
    scanf("%s",fileName);
    //open the input file
    FILE *fp=fopen(fileName, "r");
    //check if file exists or not
    if (fp=fopen("results.dat","r")== NULL)     {
        printf("File could not be opened.\n");
        //if not exit, close the program
        exit(0);
    }
    //read temperatures from the file input.txt until end of file is encountered
    while(fscanf(fp,"%d",&temperature)!=EOF)    {
        //store the values in the temp array
        temp[counter]=temperature;
        //increment the counter by one
        counter++;
    }
    //close the input file stream fp
    fclose(fp);
}

void calc_results(int temp[], int size)    {
    int i, min, max, sum = 0;
    float avg;
    min = temp[0];
    max = temp[0];
    //Loop that calculates min,max, sum of array
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)    {
        if (temp[i] < min)    {
            min = temp[i];
        }
        if (temp[i] > max)    {
            max = temp[i];
        }
        sum = sum + temp[i];
    }
    avg = (float) sum / size;
    //open an external output file
    FILE *fout=fopen("output.txt","w");
    //Temperature for the day of October 14, 2015
    fprintf(fout,"Temperature conditions on October 14, 2015:\n");
    fprintf(fout,"\nTime of day\tTemperature in degrees F\n\n");
    //write time of day and temperature
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)    {
        fprintf( fout,"%d \t\t%d\n",i,temp[i]);
    }
    printf("\nMin Temperature for the day is : %d\n", min);
    printf("Max Temperature for the day is :%d\n", max);
    printf("Average Temperature for the day is : %f\n", avg);
    //write min ,max and avg to the file "output.txt"
    fprintf(fout,"\nMin Temperature for the day is : %d\n", min);
    fprintf(fout,"Max Temperature for the day is :%d\n", max);
    fprintf(fout,"Average Temperature for the day is : %f\n", avg);
    //close the output file stream
    fclose(fout);
}
```

Comment: Which file can't be found? The input file or the output file?

Comment: My first guess is : You should print out which directory you are actually writing to.  My hint is : There is a difference between "./output.txt" and just "output.txt". :-)

Comment: [this is the file](https://cluster13-files.instructure.com/courses/1172924/files/52804716/course%20files/temperatures.txt?download=1&inline=1&sf_verifier=8437ffa948329ef02f1f4b46afbc74b3&ts=1459218438&user_id=3964210) that cannot be found which is the input

Comment: @MarkManning There's no difference between `filename` and `./filename`.

Comment: `fp=fopen("results.dat","r")== NULL` 1)rewrite fp. 2) needs `( )` `(fp=fopen("results.dat","r"))== NULL`

Comment: "./file" = THIS DIRECTORY YOU ARE CURRENTLY IN. "file" = Whatever directory you are currently pointing to. :-)

Comment: Is the input file in your project directory or the directory you're in when you run the program? Relative filenames are interpreted relative to your current directory, not the directory of the program.

Comment: @MarkManning If a filename has no directory prefix, it's interpreted relative to your current directory.

Comment: It's no wonder that the file you link to in your comment that can't be found: it's probably on a completely different server. Perhaps you first need to download that file.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Post that as an answer.

Comment: @Barmar: Incorrect. A relative path could be pointing to where the compiler is located. Using the "./" means THIS Directory. :-)

Comment: @MarkManning That's not how the kernel interprets relative pathnames.

Comment: @Barmar - it is on my machine. :-)  Also, absolute paths are better than relative paths. So "C:/this/is/my/path/output.txt" is even better than "./output.txt". :-)

Comment: I am with Barmar - BLUEPIXY is correct. :-) +1 to BLUEPIXY

Comment: Would you please elaborate what I need to change? I tried @BLUEPIXY suggestions but I'm still coming up with the same error.

Comment: @MarkManning: What "machine" are you on that interprets a relative pathname as not relative to the current directory?

Comment: @MarkManning: *could be pointing to where the compiler is located*. Nonsense, unless the executable is running from where the compiler is located. The relative path is based on the current folder, on your machine and every other machine.

Comment: @CarlosRecinos try `if (fp=fopen("results.dat","r")== NULL) {` change to `if(fp == NULL) {`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thank you it works!

Comment: @PaulGriffiths : No. What I meant and mean is that "C:/path/file" is not necessarily the same as "./file" or even "file". They can be three different things.

Comment: @KenWhite : That's correct and what I meant. The first "C:/path/file" is an absolute path which means the file is absolutely supposed to be at that location.  The second "./file" means where ever you currently are located (like if you do a chdir c:/path then the "./" refers to that "c:/path".  The last refers to where ever the program happens to reside OR on some systems is the directory you ran the program from. Example: I am in c:/a/b/c and I run the program in c:/d/e/f. Where do you think "file" is going to read or write to? "C:/a/b/c"? or "C:/d/e/f"?

Comment: @MarkManning: Again, what "machine" are you on where `"./file"` and `"file"` may not refer to the same file? You claimed your machine behaves like this - what machine is it?

Comment: @PaulGriffiths : Think of it this way: My path statement either does or does not contain "." as one of the paths. In directory "/x/y/z" is a file called input.txt. If I just say "input.txt" then it will use "/x/y/a/input.txt" but if I say "./input.txt" then it will use the one in the directory I am in.  Got it?

Comment: @MarkManning : Again, please identify the machine for which you are claiming that `fopen()` will not treat `"input.txt"` as a file in the current directory, that will not treat it the same as `"./input.txt"`. This is nothing to do with your path statement, since `fopen()` will not make use of your path statement on any system of which I am aware, quite besides the fact that path statements in general are relevant only to locating executable programs.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Any unix system should do this. Actually, HTML will do this also.  You can specify a relative path (../images/X.jpg ) or an absolute path ( C:/mywebsite/images/X.jpg ) or if your path is set for it just (X.jpg).

Comment: @PaulGriffiths : Try changing your PATH environment variable so "." is the last (instead of the first) place to look.  Make two files. One with "1" in it and the other with "2" in it. Now put the directory where the "2" is as the first place to look. That is what should be picked up. Change it back to the "." as the first part of the PATH statement and it should say "1". Oh yeah - don't forget to rehash.

Comment: @MarkManning : That's absolute nonsense, no UNIX system's implementation of `fopen()` will search the directories specified in `PATH`. Relative paths will be relative to the current working directory only.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths : Maybe on YOUR systems - but not on ones I've worked on before. :-) I have had to work on some very strange set-ups and I have run into this on different occasions. I am glad you have not (or never) had to deal with this type of a problem before.  But that doesn't mean it doesn't exist. :-)

Comment: @MarkManning : No - but the fact it doesn't exist DOES mean that it doesn't exist. At least you appear to have retracted your very recent claim that "any UNIX system should do this", which it certainly should not, and neither does "your machine".

Comment: @PaulGriffiths : No - the systems I am talking about were all Unix systems. So no - I have not recanted anything. :-) The files can be in two places and fopen() will open the first one it finds. At least on the systems I am talking about. I can tell you the systems were at NASA but I can't say anything else about them (just like on my resume). :-)

Comment: @MarkManning : OK. I acknowledge your inability to support your spurious and incorrect claims. No more need for me to comment.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths : Whatever - but when you do run in to this one day - remember what I've said here and hopefully it will help you out then. :-)

Answer (score 0):

To check whether file exist you have to use "access()" function. For that first include  as:

```
#include <unistd.h>          // For "access()" function
#include <errno.h>           // For "errno"
#include <string.h>          // For "strerror()" function
// add your stuffs here ...
// .....
// .....
int status = access(filename, F_OK);
int saved_error = errno;              // For errno include <errno.h>
if (status == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "File Error: %s\n", strerror(saved_error));
    // For "strerror" include <string.h>
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
// Now here file will exist and can be opened as:
FILE *fptr = fopen(filename, "r");
saved_error = errno;    // Read more about errno: "man errno" commend in linux
// check for error 
if(fptr == NULL){
   fprintf(stderr, "File error: %s\n", strerror(saved_error);
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
// Now access you file using fptr...
```